# SharpMap Selecting Geometry with GeoAPI.Geometries

Tags: c#, spatial, sharpmap, geoapi

hi there i'm trying to create a function that will select a layers geometry and change its colour or highlight it.

I've found the `FindGeoNearPoint` function but this deals with the old `SharpMap.Geometries` whih no longer exists and has been replaced with GeoAPI.Geometries.

How do I alter the `FindGeoNearPoint` Function to use GeoAPI

Here is my attempt

```
     public SharpMap.Data.FeatureDataRow FindGeoNearPoint(GeoAPI.Geometries.IPoint pos, SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer layer, double amountGrow)
    {

        GeoAPI.Geometries.Envelope bbox = new GeoAPI.Geometries.Envelope();
        SharpMap.Data.FeatureDataSet ds = new SharpMap.Data.FeatureDataSet();

        layer.DataSource.ExecuteIntersectionQuery(bbox, ds);

        DataTable tbl = ds.Tables[0] as SharpMap.Data.FeatureDataTable;

        NetTopologySuite.IO.WKTReader reader = new NetTopologySuite.IO.WKTReader();

        GeoAPI.Geometries.IGeometry point = reader.Read(pos.ToString());

        if (tbl.Rows.Count == 0)

            return null;



        double distance = point.Distance(reader.Read((tbl.Rows[0] as SharpMap.Data.FeatureDataRow).Geometry.ToString()));

        SharpMap.Data.FeatureDataRow selectedFeature = tbl.Rows[0] as SharpMap.Data.FeatureDataRow;



        if (tbl.Rows.Count > 1)

            for (int i = 1; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                GeoAPI.Geometries.IGeometry line = reader.Read((tbl.Rows[i] as SharpMap.Data.FeatureDataRow).Geometry.ToString());

                if (point.Distance(line) < distance)
                {

                    distance = point.Distance(line);

                    selectedFeature = tbl.Rows[i] as SharpMap.Data.FeatureDataRow;

                }

            }

        return selectedFeature;

    }
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve it ?

Comment: I have just started converting a project that was using SharpMap v0.92 to v1.1.  I found GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate as a replacement for SharpMap.Geometries.Point.